# Unable to enable IPv6 for telnet server

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ipv6, telnet

I am trying to enable IPv6 on the telnet server running on Ubuntu 16.04, but I cannot.

My configuration files look like the following.

**/etc/xinetd.d/telnet**

```
service telnet
{
        disable         = no
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        wait            = no
        flags           = REUSE IPv6
}
```

**/etc/inetd.conf**

```
telnet stream tcp nowait telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
```

After /etc/init.d/xinetd restart, the telnet server is listening on only IPv4 address, not IPv6 address:

```
# netstat -nap|grep xinet
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4592/xinetd     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    31655    4592/xinetd
```

As a result, when I telnet, I see this error message:

```
# telnet -6 ::1
Trying ::1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

On the server, I have an active network interface with IPv6 address enabled, and I have been running IPv6-enabled SSH server without any problem.   But somehow I cannot enable IPv6 for telnet server.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/512273/ipv6-address-is-not-working-in-ubuntu) where The problem is solved by adding `flags = IPv6` line to `/etc/xinetd.d/echo` file (but in your case it would be `/etc/xinetd.d/telent`:

```
service echo
{
    disable     = no
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = echo-stream
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
        flags           = IPv6  
    user        = root
    wait        = no
}                                                                               


service echo
{
    disable     = no
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = echo-dgram
    socket_type = dgram
    protocol    = udp
        flags           = IPv6  
    user        = root
    wait        = yes
}
```

Comment: I already tried "flags = IPv6", but that does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too. I was able to resolve it by adding the following lines in /etc/xinetd.conf, and do, service xinetd restart.

service telnet

```
         {
                 socket_type         = stream
                 wait                = no
                 nice                = 10
                 user                = root
                 server              = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
                 flags               = IPv6
          }
```

Thanks